# EXCEL: Allocating correctly fields on different tables

Tags: excel

I have 2 sheets, were on sheet 2 I insert the value fields corresponding the type (Product or Service), and on the sheet 1, I have 2 tables corresponding to Products and Services.

As you can see on the [sample file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8cWPjnfLFzWUDhRR1ZLUWRReEE), the formula thatIi use to fetch the values on sheet 2 is not the correct, since, if there is product between services, appear a blank line.

Also, I don't know how many products/ services will be added, so there isn't any way to know how many cells I have to put on SUM() function on the tables located on sheet 1.

How can I allocate a new line of the correspondent tables (services/product) without having black lines in the middle?

How can I add automatically insert new lines on those tables and the SUM() fetch those lines?

Regards

As suggested here are the screenshots from the file:

[Sheets 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD6F3.png)

Comment: Put a few screenshots of the file, few people would download it.

Comment: Done ;). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Anyone can help me???